# Unresolved identifier on Archiving build

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

I have a problem where i want to archive my build to upload to itunesConnect.
However after implementing `adMob` and `Analytics` i get numerous (19) errors
all saying

- `Use of unresolved identifier 'GAI'`
- `Use of unresolved identifier 'kGAIScreenName'`
- `Use of unresolved identifier 'GAIDictionaryBuilder'`

etc..

i have a header file (which i cannot target a membership for);

```
// PayDay!-Bridging-Header.h  
#ifndef PayDay__Bridging_Header_h
#define PayDay__Bridging_Header_h

#import <Google/Analytics.h>

#endif /* PayDay__Bridging_Header_h */
```

Building it on `xCode` for simulator and on device's work.
It just gives me errors on building when selecting `'Generic iOS device'`.

The framework `Google/analytics` is installed through Pods.
The navigator is like the following:
[image: xCode navigator view]

How to fix this?

Update 1:

[image]

Comment: can you please take a screen shot of the errors? Are the errors from Xcode or Organizer?

Comment: @NeilAppleDeveloper i edited the post with the requested screenshot.

Comment: @Brianvandenheuvel Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @user867662 i think it was manually add the franmework. I totally forgot though. Sorry....